# How to share Windows 8 WinRT Metro style libaries/components across apps

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

The Metro documentation states that the applications are self-consistent (no shared DLL’s, etc), So I’m just wondering how you can create a modular, BIG Metro application by creating reusable components/libraries.

Considering the case for HTML5/JavaScript Metro apps, if a lot of them should contain the same CSS and JavaScript (consider jQuery, templates) or WinJS scripts then it doesn't look quite good … I expected some form of libraries/reuse to exist from the start.

The HDD space is definitely cheap nowadays but I think that a versioned library repository should be in place and the dependencies (WinRT components/libraries, JavaScript libraries...etc) should be loaded on demand (if not already available). No "wheel invention" here needed, just look how Maven and Ivy is doing it .... otherwise will find out that our beloved jQuery 1.6.4 library is deployed in tens (if not hundreds) of applications and the bloat is ready ...

Comment: A downside of this sort of "isolated assembly" idea is what they call servicing.  Say you have 60 apps that all use your WackyWidget library, and oops you find a bug.  Sounds like you must redeploy all 60 apps to all users instead of pushing out a patch to correct the single shared DLL you'd have had in the past.

Comment: @Bob On the other hand, it may be somewhat confusing to the user when you only update the DLL. When you update an app, they see it in the list of apps to update, look at the changelog, confirm/refuse it and so on. When you update a DLL, how do you explain it to the user? It's not an app. It's something that will affect other apps. The changelog would only make sense to a programmer, not to a user.

Comment: Well when patches are pushed via Windows Update, SUS/WSUS, etc. there is no list of applications provided to the user. In the case of some libraries it could be a LOT of applications. We have the same issues here with internal applications that use quite a few widely-shared libraries among them, and seldom push out whole new install packages.  This makes sense to admins more than either programmers or users I suspect though.

Comment: The fact that they won't allow shared libraries is a really bad sign for anyone that's into component design. From a developers point of view I can't see any benefit in disallowing shared libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, each WinRT/Metro style application can access only dlls that are built into Windows or are shipped in their appx package.  There is no facility to ship centrally referenced dlls.  Each application that wants to use a dll/library will need a copy that ships with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can share libraries, you just won't be doing it using DLLs. You can easily create a class library with common utilities and functions, then reference/share it in your application. You can also drop to C++ and create your own shared functions via WinRT.

Comment: You will be doing this via DLLs actually (C++ "WinRT component" project type outputs a .dll with code and a .winmd with metadata). But you can't have a single copy of such DLL shared between several different apps.

Comment: Windows Runtime/Metro style applications cannot access shared dll's or components other than the ones that ship with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As you point out there isn't any kind of Global Assembly Cache for saving a single instance of a library/component and sharing it with any app that needs it. While the GAC in .NET is nice, I don't think very many developers take advantage of it. Hoe many one off .NET apps share component assemblies that are saved in the GAC? I believe the percentage isn't very high, consequentially all those assemblies are duplicated. The decision to not spend time on a Metro GAC seems warranted to me.

They would need to implement 3 global caches for Metro if they did build it. One for each .NET, C++ and JavaScript. It seems to make sense. This just sounds like a mess. Plus, how does the cache know that no apps on the machine use a certain assembly anymore and it can be deleted? Messy...

This is a fairly complex topic, and doesn't really have a short answer solution. No matter the debate, they may be working on a solution to this and just haven't released it in the Windows Developer Preview. More time is needed to see how the platform evolves closer to release.

Comment: They could aswell just use one storage location - considering that this is nothing but COM in the end… On the case of no longer used assemblies: how about a dependency model like package managers have had it for years now?

Comment: @MFH WinRT components can be implemented in .NET languages also, and those compile to managed assemblies, so it's not quite "nothing but COM in the end" (all system libraries are pure native though).

Comment: @Pavel: Yes it is, it's not like you couldn't access COM from .NET ever before… The WinRT infrastructure is nothing but an extended version of COM…

Comment: @MFH Yes, you could access COM from .NET before and write COM components. However, a COM component written in .NET is not "nothing but COM", since it's still a managed assembly loaded and run by CLR, and so all .NET concepts apply. Same goes for WinRT.

Comment: I think you're missing my point: The technology used in WinRT is nothing special from my point of view. It's just a COM 2.0 for me. The fact that we're extremely dependent on the registry again - way more than .NET actually - is just another sign of that. Just because a few of the supported languages (only confirmed are C♯ and VB.net) run on top of a CLR doesn't change the fact that the infrastructure is COM again.

Answer (score 0):

WinRT allows a Metro application to take a 'dependency' on a Framework object.  That object can contain all the shared DLLs, etc. that multiple applications may use.

Comment: I think the question is whether the DLLs will still be shared once deployed.

Comment: Shared in memory? Or shared on disk? A single framework object (deployed one time, with a single instance on the disk) can be used by multiple applications. When activated, it will be in the context/sandbox of the application itself, so I don't believe the memory image will be shared, though I am not certain on that point.