# Can the WinJS UI JS/HTML controls be used outside of Metro

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-metro

Can the Metro Javascript UI code be used (or tweaked easily) to be used outside of Metro
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465493.aspx
in a standalone HTML page that can be rendered in IE, CHROME, Safari, etc?

Comment: I highly, highly doubt it (at least significantly). [How to share Windows 8 WinRT Metro style libaries/components across apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443482/how-to-share-windows-8-winrt-metro-style-libaries-components-across-apps?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinJS is now open source and cross-plattform
http://try.buildwinjs.com/#listview

Answer (score 1):

Concerning new HTML5 controls used in Windows 8 application like ListView's, Microsoft submitted those to the W3C as standard HTML5 controls. Then if they're validated, you should be able to use those HTML5 controls in standalone HTML pages (not sure but Firefox already implemented some of these if I'm right).

Regarding JavaScript code, since it uses WinRT APIs you certainly won't be able to use this code through standalone HTML pages.

Hope this help.

Comment: yeah i was interested in the subset of the JS that is related to the UI look and feel. i think for the most part a shim or altnernative version could allow an easy way to make metro looking apps that work in browser + win8